# An analog of a BGG resolution in subregular case in positive characteristic

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory, positive-characteristic

Consider representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ in positive characteristic with a subregular nilpotent central character $\chi$. For every regular weight $\lambda$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, we have the simple module $L_{\chi}(\lambda)$ which is a quotient of the corresponding baby Verma module $Z_{\chi}(\lambda)$. My question is, how to resolve a given simple module $L_{\chi}(\lambda)$ with an exact sequence of direct sums of baby Verma modules?